# When does a triangle's Simson line not intersect the triangle itself?

Tags: geometry

I am reading an online course of Geometry with my kids in the topic of [Simson line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simson_line). Recall that, for a point $P$ on a triangle's circumcircle, the Simson line contains the feet of three perpendiculars from $P$ onto the triangle's side-lines.

> The course claims that there are situations that the Simson line has NO intersection with the inscribed triangle. However, I cannot think of any situation that the Simson line has no intersections with the inscribed triangle.

Could anyone help me on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example - the red line is the Simson Line - outside the triangle ABC, and the point on the circle D. Does this helps? Are you approving the answer? mark on left

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You have solved my problem!